# How to connect SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher to my Report Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I've a database running at my local SQL Server from which I created a paginated report in SSRS (Reporting Services) and now, I'd like to create a mobile dashboard in SSMRP.
But when I click Add Data and choice Report Server, there's no connection available and when I simply entry a name of my database (which is in my case DESKTOP-6JOFSAM), it does not work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt652547.aspx

Comment: I've read the page, but I don't find it too useful.